# How can I install firefox automatically, and set some settings?

Tags: firefox, automation, windows-installer

I need to install firefox on 100+ machines, I've done a few manually but its too much of a task to do the whole lot. I need to :

1. Install firefox executable
2. Set "dont import anything(from Internet Explorer)"
3. Set default browser to "no"
4. Set default browser not to check again
5. Copy a shortcut onto the desktop that goes to a specific URL

I know this should be able to be implemented with an MSI package, but could I also set those settings?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps better asked at http://serverfault.com/?  If you have AD group policy available to you, there are distribution packages and management templates out there.  But that's beyond SU's scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare a INI File and store it on your file server
see here for Writing the INI FIle:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Installer:Command_Line_Arguments

and in all the systems, run the SEtup with COmmand line

```
FirefoxSetup.exe  /S /INI=<your INIFile path>
```